# Sending Messages Through handler from Service

Tags: java, android

i use asmack buddycloud 2010 for a chat app and im trying to send chat messages from my servie to activity using handler here is the code part of my service:

```
 public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
      Message message = (Message) packet;
      if (message.getBody() != null) {
        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity ", " Text Recieved " + message.getBody() + " from " 
 +  fromName);
        messages.add(fromName + ":");
        messages.add(message.getBody());
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",message.getBody());
      mHandler.obtainMessage(123, "Message or data");
      mHandler.sendMessage(message);
```

here on the mhanlder.sendmessage i have an error saying the method sendMessage(Message message) in the type handler is not applicable for arguments (org.jivesoft.smack.packet.message)

and here in the activity :

```
 Public CLass XMPPActivity extends Activity {

 .
 .
 .

  private class getmessage extends Handler{


public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    setListAdapter();

}

 }
```

here i cant override the handlemessage, it says i must override a supertype method !!!! do you guys know what's up? am i missing some thing? thanks

also when i replace it with

```
 mHandler.obtainMessage(123, message).sendToTarget();


i get nothing, because i can not override the handleMessage()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by following way.

#### Step 1

Declare `Handler` inside your activity say inside `onCreate` method.

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case PASS:
            String obj = msg.obj.toString();
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "PASS",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case FAIL:
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "FAIL",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

#### Step 2

Declare 2 constants which are used in `Handler`

```
public static final int PASS = 1;
public static final int FAIL = 2;
```

#### Step 3

To pass message, use following code.

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.what = PASS;
msg.obj = fromName;
```

Here, you can change `msg.what` to any integer constant. And you can set any type of object to `msg.obj`. But make sure that what type of object you are setting to it, you need to type cast it based on that only. Otherwise exception will be thrown.

Comment: well thanks alot, i fixed it using otto library just 5minutes ago after 2 days TRYING, but i appreciate it :)))

Comment: @user3660198.. i am also trying to use otto library...but my #@Subscribe method inside activity is not getting called...can u please post your answer?